# iPhone WebApp - Running completely offline

Tags: iphone, web-applications, manifest, offline

I have my iPhone WebApp actually running offline and caching all assets.

When I save it to the desktop and run the app, the webapp will continue to call
main.manifest (this was specified in my HTML tag as per the documentation).

Also I have setup my .htaccess file as below, and restarted apache

```
AddType text/cache-manifest  .manifest
```

Because I am thinking of deploying a huge amount of WebApps that I would prefer would stay completely offline, I do not want the WebApp to check/re-request the .manifest file as it currently does everytime you start the app.

Is it possible to set the app up so once it is saved the app stays **"completely offline**"

Thanks, John.

Comment: Did you know that you can answer your own question? Not only do you get the points, but we get to see the answer! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Someone at Adobe was kind enough to write up a refreshingly brief answer:

http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/11/building-an-offline-mobile-web-application.html

Comment: Unfortunately that's a Dead link